# Hibernate composite-element is not saved to DB after change

Tags: java, hibernate

I faced with issue when try to save object contains composite-element to DB.

I have next DB structure

CREATE TABLE "Security"."USERS" (

```
    "ID_USER"            INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "NAME"               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    "PSW_HASH"           VARCHAR(255)
```

)

CREATE TABLE "Security"."OBJECTS" (

```
    "ID_OBJECT"          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "CODE"               VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "NAME"               VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

)

CREATE TABLE "Security"."USERSOBJECTSRIGHT" (

```
    "ID_USEROBJECT"      INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "ID_OBJECT"          INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Security.OBJECTS(ID_OBJECT),
    "ID_USER"            INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Security.USERS(ID_USER),
    "RIGHT"              SMALLINT NOT NULL
```

)

I mapped many-to-many relationship to my model like this

```
<class name="CPUser"
           table="Security.USERS" mutable="true">
        <!-- simple property mapping-->
        <set name="userRights" table="Security.USERSOBJECTSRIGHT" inverse="true" lazy="false"                     fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="ID_USER" not-null="true"/>
            </key>
            <composite-element class="app.domain.CPUserRights">
                <many-to-one name="rights" column="ID_OBJECT" class="app.domain.CPRights" lazy="false"/>
                <property name="right" type="int" column="RIGHT"/>
            </composite-element>

        </set>
    </class>

 <class name="app.domain.CPRights"
           table="Security.OBJECTS" mutable="false">

        <!-- simple property mapping-->
    </class>

<class name="CPUserRights"
           table="Security.USERSOBJECTSRIGHT" mutable="true">

        <property
                name="right"
                type="java.lang.Integer"
                column="RIGHT"
                />
    </class>
```

Read is ok and if i try to change simple properties (like name) in User class, they also are changed in DB.

But when i try to change data in composite element for User like this:

```
    CPUser user = userService.getCPUser(id);

    for (CPUserRights rights : user.getUserRights()) {
        rights.setRight(2);
    }

    userService.updateCPUser(user);
```

this data isn't store to DB.

I do not understand why. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution: I manually stored data from composite element, like that

CPUser user = userService.getCPUser(id);

```
for (CPUserRights rights : user.getUserRights()) {
    rights.setRight(2);

    userRightService.updateCPUserRights(rights);
}
```

// userService.updateCPUser(user);